# $smt->get_result() gives empty result after MySQL (only) INSERT

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing a user registration in PHP and I'm trying to check, if user account after `INSERT` was actually created. What am I doing wrong? `$dataR` variable returns nothing, so after every registration, account is created, but the script still returns **"Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again."**

Thanks for response, feel free to ask!

Connection:

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Register.php:

```
$username = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES));
$useremail = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES));
$password = $_POST['password_new'];
$options = [
    'cost' => 10,
];
$salt = $this->random_str(64);
$salted_password = $password . $salt;
$password_hash = password_hash($salted_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

$query = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT name, mail FROM users WHERE name = ? OR mail = ?");
$query->bind_param('ss', $username, $useremail);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->get_result(); // this works fine

if($results->num_rows == 1) {
    $row = $results->fetch_object();
    
    if($username == $row->name) {
        $this->errors[] = "This username is already taken!";
    } elseif($useremail == $row->mail) {
        $this->errors[] = "This email address is already taken!";
    } else {
        $this->errors[] = "This username / email address is already taken.";
    }
} else {
    $SIS = new SnowflakeIdService;
    $snowflakeID = $SIS->CreateSnowflakeID();
    $sql = $this->db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (snowflake, name, salt, hash, mail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $sql->bind_param("issss", $snowflakeID, $username, $salt, $password_hash, $useremail);
    $sql->execute();
    $dataR = $sql->get_result(); // this not

    if($dataR) {
        $this->messages[] = "Your account has been created successfully. You can now log in.";
    } else {
        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there IS NO RESULT from an insert only a status True/False

Comment: If you want to know if anything was inserted, use `$stmt->affected_rows`.

Comment: ___BIG NOTE___ `password_hash()` generates its own SALT, better than anything you are likely to come up with. If you look at the manual page is says `Warning

The salt option is deprecated. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default. As of PHP 8.0.0, an explicitly given salt is ignored.
`

Comment: _Another Note:_ If you are using prepared, bound, parameteterised queries (like you are) you do not need to `real_escape_string()` the user inputs

Comment: So try `$dataR = $sql->execute(); if ( $didIt ) { // inserted ok` and remove the `$dataR = $sql->get_result(); `

Comment: Thanks! `$sql->affected_rows` works great! Also, you wrote that this code can be injected, how? And how can I use prepare statements, I use them already, don't I?

Comment: SOrry, my mistake, saw the `real_escape_string()` and made an assumption. I should know better :)

Comment: Alright, no problem. Thanks for help! I published the solution

Comment: Do not use `$this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags` It will damage your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `$dataR = $sql->get_result();` to `$dataR = $sql->affected_rows;`, so the final code looks like:

```
$sql = $this->db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (snowflake, name, salt, hash, mail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param("issss", $snowflakeID, $username, $salt, $password_hash, $useremail);
$sql->execute();
$dataR = $sql->affected_rows;
if($dataR > 0) {
     $this->messages[] = "Your account has been created successfully. You can now log in.";
} else {
     $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.";
}
```

Comment: Checking for `$sql->affected_rows` sounds dubious. Why do you think that the account would not get created? Make sure you have error reporting enabled [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)